# how to calculate PDF in tensorflow

Tags: python, statistics, tensorflow, probability-density

In Matlab, I can calculate the probability density function(PDF) of Gaussian distribution by using

```
x = [0.8147,0.9058,0.1270,0.9134,0.6324,0.0975,0.2785,0.5469,0.9575,0.9649]
y = normpdf(x,1.0,2.5)
```

output:

```
y = 0.1591    0.1595    0.1501    0.1595    0.1579    0.1495    0.1531    0.1570    0.1596    0.1596
```

Using tensorflow, I have tried with this

```
x = tf.variable([0.8147,0.9058,0.1270,0.9134,0.6324,0.0975,0.2785,0.5469,0.9575,0.9649],tf.float32)
y = tf.contrib.distributions.NormalWithSoftplusSigma.pdf(x)
```

I get an error `TypeError: pdf missing 1 required positional argument`

how to input the mu and sigma values to this distribution ? to get the similar output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a `Normal distributions` object and then use the `pdf` method

```
dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(1.0, 2.5)
y = dist.pdf(x)
```

See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard7/tf.contrib.distributions.Normal.md) for more details.

Comment: The link to details is dead

Answer (score 5):

This function `pdf` is updated as `prob`:

```
dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(1.0, 2.5) 
y = dist.prob(x)
```